# Python: Using timer with PyHook

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, time, pyhook

I am attempting to use PyHook to disable keyboard and mouse while running the script, and I am having difficulties setting a timer function so that the keyboard and mouse will only be disabled for a predefined amount of time, e.g. 30 seconds, and then return to normal.

```
def windoow(event):
    while True:
        return False
        time.sleep(30)
        break

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = windoow
hm.KeyAll = windoow
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I am new to programming in general, and I am therefore hoping for an easy solution that I can learn from and understand.

Thank you.

Comment: You aren't calling the function. You also have for windoow event which needs to be passed too.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! When I run the above code it disables both keyboard and mouse, but how can set the timer for it? Can I call windoow() and set the time.sleep there, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, This is pretty nefarious but this does work. Your time.sleep() was never executing because it was placed after a return statement

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, time
start = time.time()
time.clock()
elapsed = 0

def windoow(event):
    global elapsed
    if elapsed < 30:
       elapsed = time.time() - start
       time.sleep(1)
       return False

    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = windoow
hm.KeyAll = windoow
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: Absolutely :) Thanks again. I will also upvote once I have enough reputation.